# how can my application  remember username and password after the user logs in?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

When the user check "remember me" i want to save the username and password.
The user should be able to login directly the next time.
What is the best way to do this?

I tried isolated storage but maybe the code i wrote is incorrect.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Post your code so that we can see what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great how-to on how to [Encrypt Data in a Windows Phone Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487164%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) - it may be worth comparing that code with yours

Answer (score 0):

The best and secure way to do this.. Is storing unique ID which are relevant only to the servers that you are talking to as cookies.

Algo:

1. Get the username and password from the user
2. Check for authenticity of the user.
3. If authenticated, then generate an unique ID  relevant to this user and store it on server.
4. Pass on this unique ID to client side and store this in a cookie. Set the max-age
5. Next time when the user come to your site. Check for the unique ID on the server and also check its age as well as when it was issued
6. If all's well , then give access to user

Comment: i want to write it as code ,, i don't want to check the authenticate i just want to save the username and password , the next time he enter the app without put the username and password another time thnx for ur help anyway :)

Comment: I guess then its upto you. But this app wont be secure

Comment: ok the how i could write what u send to me  as code mmmm because i didn't get the idea as good as i think

Comment: @Sanket IsolatedStorage allows encryption of settings on the phone, so security needn't be sacrificed

Comment: @rowland : i was not having any idea about this. Thanks for that information.